# How to resize an image within a cell in longtable environment while keeping its aspect?

Tags: graphics

### Problem

I am currently writing a table with `longtable` environment, and would like to **insert a picture within a cell** and **vertically center-align** it. However, my try ends up as follows:

[image]

So what I would like to do is as follows:

- If the boy was taller than the cell, then reducing his height to the cell while keeping aspect.
- If the boy was fatter than the cell, then reducing his width to the cell while keeping aspect.

--

### Try

The above table was generated using the following code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12bp]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|ccc|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column1} } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column3}} \\ \hline \endhead 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} \medskip \scriptsize \lipsum[4] \medskip \end{minipage}} & \\ \cline{2-2} 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\Large Name1}} &

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} \medskip \scriptsize \lipsum[2] \medskip \end{minipage}} & 
\multirow{-10}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{figure}[H]{\center \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true, width=\linewidth]{figures/human.png}} \end{figure} \end{minipage}} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

### Question

How should I put this boy within the cell while keeping his aspect? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Several things wrong here. (1) no need for the figure env as there is no caption, (2) you mean `\centering` not `\center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

- float figure had not to be enclosed in `minipage` or similar box environment
- image, included by `includegraphics[width=<length>]{<image-file>}` is keeps own aspect ratio
- instead of use `minipage` in cells is better to define column type `p{<width>}`
- I didn't change your code for columns headers
- for `multirow` in the last column you can use option defined in recent `multirow` package: `{=}`

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12bp]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow, longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c 
                  |>{\scriptsize}p{0.4\textwidth}
                  |p{0.5\textwidth}|}
    \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column1} } 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column2}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large \textbf{Column3}} \\ 
    \hline 
\endhead
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
    & \lipsum[4] 
        &   \\ 
    \cline{2-2}
\multirow{-1}{*}{\Large Name1}
    &   \scriptsize \lipsum[2]
        &   \multirow{-6.2}{=}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}} \\ 
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```